# How to create multple menu using $menu.menu in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I am creating menu using method

```
var getMenuItem = function (itemData) {
        var item = $("<li style='display: block;' onclick='showDetails(this)' data-type='"+itemData.name+"'>")
            .append(
        $("<a>", {
            href: '#' + itemData.link,
            html: itemData.name
        }));
    criteriaSeq++;  
    if (itemData.sub) {
        var subList = $("<ul>");
        name.push(itemData.name);
      //  console.log("Push"+name.toString());
        $.each(itemData.sub, function () {
            subList.append(getMenuItem(this));
        });
        item.append(subList);
        }
    //$("#padho").append("<p>"+name+"</p>")
    //console.log("After if"+name.toString());  
    return item;
};

var $menu = $("#menu");
$.each(data.menu, function () {
    $menu.append(
        getMenuItem(this)
    );
});
$menu.menu();
```

my requirement is to call this method in onclick of function from span and create menu(multiple menu in same page).

Please let me know if any one have any idea on this issue i tried

```
<ul id="menu-'sequence'" class="criteria_key"  style="width: 100px;"></ul>
```

menu is not creating.

Comment: I am using JSON data fro creating dynamic jquery menu.

Comment: try the light weight and multilevel responsive menu -> 
 https://github.com/hidaytrahman/hr-navigation-responsive-menu